# linear programming problem for minimum cost

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming, operations-research

A construction company has 6 projects, for each they need `$d_i$` workers. The company has no workers at the beginning of project 1.

Each new worker must take a safety course that costs 300, and 50 more for each worker.
If there is no new worker there is no course.

Firing a worker does not cost any money, and a workers can't be rehired.

Given that the salary of a worker is 100 per project, formulate a linear programming problem that minimizes the workers costs.

What I tried:

Let `$x_i$` be the number of new workers for project `$i$`.

Let `$y_i$` be the number of old workers remaining from previous projects until project `$i$` (all the workers hired - all the workers that were fired)

Let `$z_i$` be an indicator such that `$z_i =0 \iff x_i>0$`

The function I'm trying to solve is:

```
$\min(\sum_{i=1}^6 150x_i + 300(1-z_i) + 100y_i)$
```

s.t:

```
\begin{align}
x_i,y_i,z_i &\ge 0 \\
z_i &\ge 1-x_i \\
y_i + x_i &\ge d_i \\
y_i &\ge y_{i-1} + x_i
\end{align}
```

Something feels not right to me. The main reason is that I tried to use matlab to solve this and it failed.

What did I do wrong? How can I solve this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I see this correctly you have two small mistakes in your constraints.

The first appears when you use `z_i >= 1-x_i`. This allows `z_i` to take the value 1 all the time, which will never give you the extra cost of 300. You need to upper bound `z_i` such that z_i will not be 1 when you have `x_i>0`. For this constraint you need something called [big M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_M_method). For sufficiently large `M` you would then use `z_i <= 1-x_i/M`. This way when `x_i=0` you can have `z_i=1`, otherwise the right hand side is smaller than 1 and due to integrality `z_i` has to be zero. Note that you usually want to choose `M` as tight as possible. So in your case `d_i` might be a good choice.

The second small mistake lays in `y_i >= y_{i-1} + x_i`. This way you can increase `y_i` over `y_{i-1}` without having to set any `x_i`. To force `x_i` to increase you need to flip the inequality. Additionally by the way you defined `y_i` this inequality should refer to `x_{i-1}`. Thus you should end up with `y_i <= y_{i-1} + x_{i-1}`. Additionally you need to take care of corner cases (i.e. `y_1 = 0`)

I think with these two changes it should work. Let me know whether it helped you. And if it still doesn't work I might have missed something.